# Photometry and plant growth

Tags: light

What unit of photometry is used to assess plant growth? Is there a catalog that lists plants and the required light exposure? I'm looking at more detailed indicators than "a lot of light" or "not too much light".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a topic covered by this site (see the help center). I would ask it at biology.stackexchange.com.